# Destroy not destroying GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I have the following code in Unity3D for adding and deleting a line segment for a 3D drawing:

```
public class LinearPiecewiseTrajectory : MonoBehaviuor
{
    private List<LineSegment> lineSegmentRep;

    //other stuff here

    public void addSegment()
    {
        GameObject lineSegmentObject = new GameObject();
        lineSegmentObject.name = "LineSegment";

        LineSegment lineSegment = lineSegmentObject.AddComponent<LineSegment>();

        lineSegmentObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
        lineSegmentRep.Add(lineSegment);
    }
}

public void deleteSegment(int i)
{
    Destroy(lineSegmentRep[i]);
}
```

LineSegment is a MonoBehavior I have defined.

However, this destroy call isn't actually destroying the LineSegment object.  The only discernible behavior I can find is that it's setting the old LineSegment's geometric transform back to identity.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> However, this destroy call isn't actually destroying the LineSegment
>   object

When you call `Destroy(componentName);`, the component that is passed in will be destroyed but the GameObject the component is attached to will **not** be destroyed.

If you want the GameObject to destroy with all the scripts attached to it then `Destroy(componentName.gameObject);` should be used.

So replace `Destroy(lineSegmentRep[i]);` with `Destroy(lineSegmentRep[i].gameObject);`.

Also before destroying each LineSegment, it is important that you also remove them from the List so that you won't have an empty/null LineSegment in that `lineSegmentRep` List.

```
public void deleteSegment(int i)
{
    //Remove from the List
    lineSegmentRep.Remove(lineSegmentRep[i]);
    //Now, destroy its object+script
    Destroy(lineSegmentRep[i].gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it is destroying the component of type LineSegment.

You need to tell to destroy the game object.

```
Destroy(lineSegmentRep[i].gameObject);
```